# Build a championship table in PHP from 3 MySQL tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display a championship table from the 3 tables I have in my MySQL database.

`tbl_champ` holds the championship name (nitro) and date (2015). `tbl_rounds` holds the round name (round1 so on) the date (01/01/2015 so on) and the `champ_id`. `tbl_position` holds the `round_id`, `positions` (1, 2, 3 etc) and `racer_id` (2, 4, 8 etc).

Inserting and updating the tables work great, but I cannot seem to get them to display as I want.

This is what I have:

```
echo '<table border="1">';

$sql_rou = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `rounds`") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_rou = mysql_fetch_array($sql_rou)) {
$rid = $row_rou[0];   

echo '<th>' . $row_rou[1] . '</th>';

$sql_pos = mysql_query("SELECT `pos_user_id` FROM `positions` WHERE `pos_round_id`='$rid'") or die(mysql_error());

while ($pos_info = mysql_fetch_row($sql_pos)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($pos_info as $field) {
        echo '<td>'.$field.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

}

}
echo '</table>';
```

But I get:

```
ROUND 1
[20]
[2]
ROUND 2
[2]
[20]
```

Any way to get the rounds next to each other, but keeping the []'s as they are?

[image: Excel table]

(I've built the table in Excel).

Any ideas? Am I just thinking about this all wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at where you close the brackets for the `<th>` entries. It should be about line 6 of your sample code. You have it at the bottom of the page. This will loop every result for each header value.

Also, you don't seem to have any `<tr>` in your `<thead>`. Think of your `<th>` as cells, like `<td>`, which need to be wrapped in a row.